# Touchscreen problems with a rk2918 tablet

Tags: touchscreen

I have an Evolio Evotab 2 (RK2918) running gingerbread

http://www.gsmland.ro/tableta-evolio-evotab_2-4090

(sorry couldn't find english site with specs)

When typing fast it repeats the last letter instead of the one I just pressed. (for instance If I type Q and quickly go to K I get QQ )

I tried flashing other roms from similar chinese tablets but couldn't find one where everything worked.

Also it happens more often in landscape than when typing in portrait mode.

Can anybody tell me if this sounds like a software or hardware issue?

This is what I tried so far:
-other keyboards than stock
-tried typing in different places (browsers,apps)
-other rom's
-wipe+flash+root and uninstall allmost everything with TB = still happens.

Thank you.

Comment: Try calibrating the touchscreen, sounds like the calibration is off!!!

Comment: Tried it, downloaded tscalibration.apk, did the calibration thing and restarted... no luck

Answer (score -1):

Hmmm.. a quick google-fu yielded this [linky](http://en.shop.evolio.ro/howtos/view/5/)

To quote:

> GPS: What should I do if touch screen ( display) is not responding? In
>   case that the product is E100, E205, E300 or E400 press the RESET key.
>
> If is S1200, A1700 or Xroad, follow the steps:
>
> 1. Turn on the device and press key Menu M (up left), in case the GPS is turning on rolling an application it will return to the home
>      menu.
> 2. In home menu press key Menu then press 4 times key +( plus, up right) and once key – (minus, down right).
> 3. If the steps were correct executed, on screen will appear a cursor +. Press, with careful, in the      center of the cursor using
>      the GPS pencil, marking the screen coordonats, center and four
>      corners.
> 4. After marking the coordonates, touch the screen anywhere for saving the coordonates.
> 5. Next step “Touch Test” will confirm that the settings are right and will have effect on the device, press the center of + and if the 5
>      coordonates were been set correctly  it will pass at sound test, or it
>      will return at the calibrating screen .
> 6. If you executed correctly the steps and you arrived at “Sound Test”, turn off and then turn on the GPS.
> 7. Assure that you executed correctly the procedure  and if the problem persist, contact our service.

Try that or use one of the [hidden secret Android codes](http://d.stackexchange.com/questions/35758/how-to-view-the-android-service-menu-secret-menu) to get at the service menu, there may be an option in there to calibrate the touchscreen?

Comment: The instructions are for GPS devices with resistive screens, running windows CE. I would try the service code thing but don't know how to start the dialer on a tablet. I can see it's installed but can't find it in the app drawer... Thanks!